# What is protocol suite?

Tags: networking, tcpip, protocol

I came across protocol suite in Internet Protocol suite, and after I searched for 
it I found:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack#General_protocol_suite_description

which explains protocol stack rather than suite.

Could someone please explain what is protocol suite? It doesn't seem to be same as protocol
stack!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you see this:

> The protocol stack is an implementation of a computer networking protocol suite. The terms are often used interchangeably. Strictly speaking, the suite is the definition of the protocols, and the stack is the software implementation of them.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_stack#General_protocol_suite_description

And this:

> The Internet protocol suite is the set of communications protocols used for the Internet and similar networks, and generally the most popular protocol stack for wide area networks.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite

Comment: @Naji You have a bucketful of protocols (the suite). You pull a few out to use for your specific implementation (the stack).

Comment: @user142485 Actually could you expand your answer with a concrete example such as: For a given (real world) suite S, show two (or more) different (real world) implementations. IMO, it would help to understand much better.